# Qt C++ - constructing a QStringlist with double quotes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would need some help for something very easy which keeps on not working:

I am trying to conctruct this **QStringList** :

```
-c "import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); foo.myTestFunction();"
```

Note the quotes! But I have tried a zillion things like:

```
QStringList params;
params << "-c \"import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); foo.myTestFunction() \" ";
```

But that doesn t seem to work!

What happens:

I am trying to run a python script from my Qt gui. I can run the script when I am using the terminal as follows:

```
$ python2 -c "import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); foo.myTestFunction();"
    output: this is the python script
```

I am now trying to replicate this in my Qt C++ code as follows:

```
{
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    params << "-c \"import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py');     foo.myTestFunction() \" ";
    qDebug()<<params;
    p.start("python2 ", params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
    qDebug()<<p_stdout;
    qDebug()<<"ran py script";

}
```

yet it only outputs:

```
    "-c \"import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); foo.myTestFunction() \" "
    ""
    ran py scrip
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import os
import numpy as np

def myTestFunction():
    print('output: this is the python script')
    return 55

if __name__=='__main__':
   a = myTestFunction()
   print('returned value: '+ str(a))
```

I expected **at least** to see "55" in stead of an empty string like "". Could someoboy help me out?

Comment: QStringList is not a parser. If you need a string list, you need to provide its elements as separate strings.

Comment: @n.m. could you please *show* what you mean? Ive tried many things and chanxes are very high ive already tried what y re suggesting.

Comment: Try `params << "-c" << "import imp; foo ... etc"` (note you probably **do not** need additional quotes around the second parameter).

Comment: @n.m. 1)my script still returns nothing and 2) this is what qDebug returns (note the additional undesired comma):  ("-c ", "import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); foo.myTestFunction() ")

Comment: @n.m. I also tried to debug it using a connect as follows: connect(&p, SIGNAL(errorOccurred(QProcess::ProcessError error)), qApp, SLOT(aboutQt()) ); But I get: QObject::connect: No such signal QProcess::errorOccurred(QProcess::ProcessError error)

Comment: @dtech do those two posts give you an idea? ^

Comment: You have an extra space in yor command string. `"python2 "` is probably not a valid command on your system, try `"python2"`. "undesired comma" is a part of the syntax of the list. Also make sure you check for possible errors (see QProcess::errorOccurred).

Comment: qdebug simply decorates the output to signify separate elements

Comment: @n.m. I removed the extra space but that didn't change anything. I tried to use errorOccurred as you can see above, but that doesn't work... I tried to use the started() signal. It is never emitted and therefor know for a fine fact that there is still smth wrong with the parameters

Comment: @dtech I used connect's to debug it, but I found out that the script still isn't being ran, I therefor know there is still smth wrong with the parameters.

Comment: current situation: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25282840/ whihc outputs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25282845/

Comment: @trilolil: What is your Qt version? Here, [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) doesn't have its own `readAll()` method. It inherited it from `QIODevice`. Did you try with [QProcess::readAllStandardError()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError) and [QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput)?

Comment: @Azeem I am using Qt creator 4.3.1 based on Qt 5.9.1, I tried bot of the functions you suggested but both return an empty string: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25282984/

which returns: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25282993/

**edit:** I updated the last link with the output

Comment: @trilolil: Right. You should try and test `QProcess::waitForFinished()` for success and print the error e.g. `if ( !p.waitForFinished( -1 ) ) { ... }`.

Comment: @Azeem what exactly do you suggest me to print? Because as you can see, I am already waiting bu uisng waitForFinish(-1) and I alrteady tried to print readAllStandardError(), which returns an empty string.

Comment: @trilolil: Just want you to confirm that it failed if it returns false.

Comment: @Azeem yes it returns false

Comment: You don't need extra spaces and quotes around your parameters. `"-c "` is not a valid Python command line argument, `"-c"` is. And no quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program is run with separate arguments it returns an empty string, I still do not understand the reason. But if we concatenate everything in a single command it is able to execute the application correctly:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess p;
    QString cmd("/usr/bin/python2 -c \"import imp; foo = imp.load_source(\'myTest\', \'/home/qhipa/myTest.py\'); foo.myTestFunction()\"");
    p.start(cmd);
    qDebug()<< p.arguments();
    if (!p.waitForFinished(-1))
        qDebug() << "Make failed:" << p.errorString();
    else
        qDebug() << "Make output:" << p.readAll();
    qDebug()<<"ran py script";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
("-c", "import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/qhipa/myTest.py'); foo.myTestFunction()")
Make output: "output: this is the python script\n"
ran py script
```

Also works if we remove the quotes, it seems that at the beginning of the arguments it is not necessary to place the quotation marks even if the command requires it.

```
QProcess p;
QStringList params = QStringList()<<"-c"<<
                                    "import imp; foo = imp.load_source(\'myTest\', \'/home/qhipa/myTest.py\'); foo.myTestFunction()";
p.start("/usr/bin/python2", params);
qDebug()<< p.arguments();
if (!p.waitForFinished(-1))
    qDebug() << "Make failed:" << p.errorString();
else
    qDebug() << "Make output:" << p.readAll();
qDebug()<<"ran py script";
```

Comment: Accepted for "concatenamos" (which is afaik the Spanish variant of "we concatenate")

Comment: @trilolil Also works if we remove the quotes, it seems that at the beginning of the arguments it is not necessary to place the quotation marks even if the command requires it. :P